# How to get the keyword of a json varible?

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have a varible, if I print it out, I see this output:

[image]

Well, if I'd know the number '118', it would be easy, but in the program where I am using it, I don't know it. So is there any mode to get it without knowing that value?

Comment: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Object.keys` function to retrieve all keys of your object.

The `Object.keys` returns an array, you can then access the first element of that array like any other array.

```js
const JSONString = '{"118": {"input1": 6, "input2": 1, "input3": 3}}';
const json = JSON.parse(JSONString);

const keys = Object.keys(json);

console.log(keys[0]);
```